# Move block to a different reference block

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, xml

I need to move a subscription block from MageMonkey module.

Here is the `magemonkey.xml` file and block that I want to move:

```
<checkout_onepage_review>
    <reference name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after">
        <block type="monkey/checkout_subscribe" name="magemonkey.subscribe"
               template="magemonkey/checkout/subscribe.phtml">
            <block type="monkey/signup" name="left.monkeysignup" template="magemonkey/lists.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_review>
```

Here is my `checkout.xml` file with the review block:

```
<checkout_onepage_review translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout Overview</label>
    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before" as="items_before" translate="label">
            <label>Items Before</label>
        </block>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after" as="items_after" translate="label">
            <label>Items After</label>
        </block>
          <block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml" />
        <block type="core/template" name="checkout.onepage.review.button" as="button" template="checkout/onepage/review/button.phtml"/>
    </block>
</checkout_onepage_review>
```

I want to move the **magemonkey.subscribe** to go below the **checkout.onepage.agreements**. I tried that but didn't work:

```
  <checkout_onepage_review>
      <reference name="checkout.onepage.agreements">
          <block type="monkey/checkout_subscribe" name="magemonkey.subscribe"
                 template="magemonkey/checkout/subscribe.phtml" output="toHtml">
              <block type="monkey/signup" name="left.monkeysignup" template="magemonkey/lists.phtml"/>
          </block>
      </reference>
  </checkout_onepage_review>
```

I can move it to the **checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before** and it work fine so I am guessing this has something to do with the type of the block I am trying to move it to. I added **output="toHtml"** but that didn't work either. Any one knows what I am doing wrong?

**I also tried:**

```
<!-- Checkout -->
  <checkout_onepage_review>
      <reference name="root">
          <block type="monkey/checkout_subscribe" name="magemonkey.subscribe"
                 template="magemonkey/checkout/subscribe.phtml" output="toHtml" before="checkout.onepage.review.button">
              <block type="monkey/signup" name="left.monkeysignup" template="magemonkey/lists.phtml" />
          </block>
      </reference>
  </checkout_onepage_review>
<!-- Checkout -->
```

But still no luck.

Am I even looking in the right place? This is driving me insane now...

Answer (score 0):

Hands down people. I got it...

In `magemonkey.xml` file, I only had to change the reference name. So my code looks like this now:

```
<!-- Checkout -->
      <checkout_onepage_review>
          <reference name="checkout.onepage.agreements">
              <block type="monkey/checkout_subscribe" name="magemonkey.subscribe"
                     template="magemonkey/checkout/subscribe.phtml">
                  <block type="monkey/signup" name="left.monkeysignup" template="magemonkey/lists.phtml" />
              </block>
          </reference>
      </checkout_onepage_review>
    <!-- Checkout -->
```

Now, in the template file of the block I want it to move to (In this case, `agreements.phtml`), I had to call the block. So added this one line to the file:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('magemonkey.subscribe') ?>
```

That solved my problem! I hope it will help someone.